# how to re-iterate a for loop within a method in python?

Tags: python, opencv, for-loop, recursion, methods

I am trying to create an image recognition bot using OpenCV. I use multiple templates, therefore I have two main parts of the code:

1 - I run a for loop to append all the templates into a list:

```
template_data=[] #global variable
files1 = glob.glob('templates\\img_*.png')
for myfile in files1:
    image = cv2.imread(myfile,cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    template_data.append(image)
```

2 - I use a method to match the templates:

```
click = [] #global variable
def findClickPositions():
    for tmp in template_data: #this for loop works fine
        result = cv2.matchTemplate(test_image, tmp, method)
        locations = np.where(result >= threshold)
        locations = list(zip(*locations[::-1]))
        rectangles = [] #local variable
        for loc in locations: #this for loop iterates only once!! 
            rect = [int(loc[0]), int(loc[1]), tmp_w, tmp_h] #rect for each loc
            rectangles.append(rect)
            print('rectangles')
        click.append((x,y))
    return click
```

So in order to run it forever, I use the main function, eg:

```
def main():
    while True:
        click = findClickPositions()
```

and calling it like so:

```
if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

When I run the code, it runs the method and for loop inside that method, but when it iterates second time and more, it does not reiterate the for loop within the method findClickPositions().

In other words, it reruns the method as intended, but it runs the for loop inside the method only during the first iteration.

I believe it has something to do with the local variable **rectangles = []** But I haven't found a solution yet.
Can anyone explain me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is it possible that you're changing the content of the ```template_data``` list accidentally? Maybe try printing that out at the start of every call to ```findClickPositions```.

Comment: Hi Johannes! I found out that the first for loop within the method works fine, but when I declare a local array, the next nested for loop that is based on that array does not re-iterate second time.

Comment: What is ``locations``?

Comment: Hi MisterMiyagi, locations = np.where(result >= threshold) -----> locations = list(zip(*locations[::-1])) , whereas "result" is the outcome of the cv2.matchTemplate. Locations are within the first for loop of this method.

Comment: @MishaBro And are you sure that `np.where(result >= threshold)` actually gives back anything the second time around? I don't really think that the problem lies in the iteration, I think that it's being skipped because it's an empty iterator.

Comment: So then, what is ``threshold``? What changes between runs of ``findClickPositions``, i.e. what is the point of re-running it?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, threshold is a value, in my case its 0.1. The screen updates between the runs, so I need to analyze the new screen over and over again

Comment: @HampusLarsson, yes indeed it returns the values only at the first iteration! But what is the problem?

Comment: @MishaBro If you launch a loop over an empty iterator, nothing inside of the loop will execute, because the exit-condition will be met immediately. If you run the code `for i in []:print(i)` then nothing will be printed, because the iterator (the list) is empty.

Comment: @HampusLarsson, wow, thank you so much for helping to understand the problem! Indeed its not the problem with the iterator. But then how can I run it so locations returns me new values during the next iterations?